# Simple_form_for form tag

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I'm having weird issue, while simple form not creating  `<form>` tag, but creates all inputs

My code looks like:

```
= simple_form_for @cost, url: cost_url, html: {remote:true, id: 'new_cost_form'}  do |f|
          = f.input :name, placeholder: "Cost name"
          = f.input :factor, as: :text, :input_html => { 'rows' => 5}
          = f.input :is_default, as: :boolean, label: "Default"
```

And this code produces me single inputs(with proper names) but there is no html `<form>` tag on page(i've tried to exec in browser console `$('#new_cost_form')` and there was empty array

Did i miss something? I've created lots of forms this way, but only this didn't work.

Comment: Though I'm not entirely sure, `remote:true` may have something to do with the lack of form since it is meant for ajax calls.

Comment: You have tagged html but your code is in Haml. If you are using HTML just make sure you have closed all the tags properly. If you are using Haml then you should see form tag as you are using `=`. If you'll post your full form then may be someone will be able to point out something

Comment: Turned out, that there was another form on top of my code, which i didn't notice due to lots of code, so solved it by moving my code outside of that form tag